# Python вывод текста параллельно с вводом

Tags: python

Набросал простейший GUI с полем ввода и вывода и хочу сделать так, чтобы поле вывода актуализировалось в режиме реального времени, без необходимости нажимать на какую-либо кнопку. То есть ввожу что-то в поле ввода и одновременно вижу вводимое в поле вывода.

Для простоты общения, вот GUI:

```
from tkinter import *

fenster=Tk()
fenster.geometry('200x200')
Eingabefeld=Entry(fenster)
Ausgabefeld=Label(fenster,text="")
Eingabefeld.focus()

Eingabefeld.pack()
Ausgabefeld.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Нашёл аналог Binding из C# в Python, думаю поможет. Вот ссылка: https://younglinux.info/tkinter/bind.php

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо за совет про bind(). Решил проблемку, прилагаю код.

```
def change(event):
    Ausgabefeld.config(text=Eingabefeld.get())

from tkinter import *

Fenster=Tk()
Fenster.geometry('200x200')

Eingabefeld=Entry(Fenster)
Ausgabefeld=Label(Fenster,text="Тут будет виден ваш текст")
Eingabefeld.focus()

Eingabefeld.pack()
Ausgabefeld.pack()

Eingabefeld.bind('<KeyRelease>',change)

mainloop()
```